# NoMethodError (undefined method `chomp!' for nil:NilClass) when using authenticate_or_request_with_http_token

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json, authentication, http-headers

I am creating API for Mobile APP

I want to authorize my request with auth_token. I followed the Rails Cast securing API and wriiten the following code

```
def restrict_access
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
  ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
  end
end
```

When i tested with curl post request using Auth token it works fine

```
curl  -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'   -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/1/events#create -H 'Authorization: Token token="024cac6efc2a75905ee2aa9cfabae020"' -d  '{ "event":{"address":"Leo Technosoft, Magarpatta", "description":"Gettogether of employees", "name":"iPhone event"}}'
```

But if get the request from IOS APP i am getting the error like

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `chomp!' for nil:NilClass):
```

The request from IOS looks like

```
{
Accept = "application/json";
"Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
"Authorization:Token token" = 024cac6efc2a75905ee2aa9cfabae020;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
"User-Agent" = "Quickvent/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 7.0; Scale/2.00)";
}
```

It is same to my curl request

```
 POST /users/1/events HTTP/1.1
 > User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
 > Host: localhost:3000
 > Content-Type: application/json
 > Accept: application/json
  > Authorization: Token token="024cac6efc2a75905ee2aa9cfabae020"
 > Content-Length: 116
  > 
 * upload completely sent off: 116out of 116 bytes
 < HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
 < Location: http://localhost:3000/users/1/events/6
```

I am not able to understand what's the problem.

Thanks

Comment: What does this method do `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token`?  Can you post it please

Comment: we’ll pass the access token in via an HTTP header. Rails gives us some controller methods to make adding this functionality easy. We can use authenticate_or_request_with_http_token

Comment: Can you try with a space after `Authorization:` and have the token in double quotes like `"Authorization: Token token" = "024cac6efc2a75905ee2aa9cfabae020";`

Comment: i tried too but no luck

Comment: I am not sure but I did something in one of the applications when I was creating APIs for an iOS app. I think they used "Authorization" as key and "Token token=024cac6efc2a75905ee2aa9cfabae020" as the value for setting the request header. Can you please try it.

Comment: awesome man thank u post as a answer i will accept